# como ordenar ficheiros csv em python pelos valores de uma coluna? Está a dar erro

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os.path

import csv

from operator import itemgetter

lista = []

ficheironovo = ''

ficheiro = input('Escreve o nome do ficheiro orginal: ')

sigla = input('Escreva a Sigla do curso: ')

while not os.path.isfile(ficheiro):

    print(f'\nFicheiro {ficheiro} não encontrado')

    ficheiro = input('Escreva o nome do ficheiro original: ')

ficheironovo = 'Top10_' + sigla + '.csv'

print(ficheiro)

print(ficheironovo)

with open (ficheiro, "r") as f:

    dados = csv.DictReader(f)

    lista = list(dados)

    for line in dados:

        print(line)

        print(line['média'])


    lista_ordenada = sorted(lista, key = itemgetter[2], reverse = True)

    for x in lista_ordenada:

        print(x)
```

Comment: Primeiramente, seja bem vindo. Por favor, não seja tão displicente. O que exatamente significa "está a dar erro?" Que erro é este? E mais, procure consultar as recomendações da plataforma, saiba [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto) usando o parametro `key` para passar um [`lambda`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) function, ficando +/- como mostrado no exemplo abaixo:

```
lista = [
    ["Maria", 15],
    ["João", 26],
    ["Jonas", 14],
    ["Fernando", 23]
]

ordenar =  sorted(lista, key=lambda row:row[1] )
#                                           ^ idx usada para o sort

print( ordenar )
# saida:  [['Jonas', 14], ['Maria', 15], ['Fernando', 23], ['João', 26]]

# ORDENAR POR MAIS DE 1 parametro
# ordenar = sorted(lista, key=lambda row:( row[1], row[0] ) )
#                                        ^ tuple com o valor o idx 1 , 0
```

<sup>[Exemplo online](https://ideone.com/RDkQLS)</sup>

```py
lista = [
    {"nome": "Maria", "idade": 15},
    {"nome": "João", "idade": 26},
    {"nome":"Jonas", "idade":14},
    {"nome":"Fernando", "idade":23}
]

ordenar =  sorted(lista, key=lambda row:row['idade'] )
#                                              ^ key usada para o sort

print( ordenar )
# saida: [{'idade': 14, 'nome': 'Jonas'}, {'idade': 15, 'nome': 'Maria'}, {'idade': 23, 'nome': 'Fernando'}, {'idade': 26, 'nome': 'João'}]

# ORDENAR POR MAIS DE 1 parametro
# ordenar = sorted(lista, key=lambda row:( row['idade'], row['nome'] ) )
#                                        ^ tuple com o valor de idade e nome
```

<sup>[Exemplo online 2](https://ideone.com/0A4BLr)</sup>